# is it possible to download roblox on the raspberry pi?

Tags: games

I'm trying to download roblox onto my raspberry pi, and whenever i do, it asks what to run it in. idk what to do

Comment: How is this in anyway related to the Pi? Please take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

Roblox is a commercial entity. For whatever reason, they have chosen [not to support linux](https://www.roblox.com/#RobloxDeviceText). Many companies make a decision to support only Windows or only Mac in the same way. You should contact Roblox and ask them to provide Linux support.